# Is it possible to force a synchronous repaint in js?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to force a synchronous repaint. Is this possible?

Unfortunately, the library I am working with sends a long-running synchronous request via `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open(_, _, false)`. I am trying to update the page with a loading indicator before the request is sent by monkey patching `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send`, however, the `opacity: 0.7` style is never seen:

```js
const oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(...args) {
  document.body.style.opacity = "0.7";

  // is there something I can do to force a repaint on this line?

  const retVal = oldSend.bind(this)(...args);
  document.body.style.opacity = "1";
  return retVal;
}
```

Most of my research suggests refactoring to something asynchronous:

- [Synchronous redraw in Webkit/Wait for DOM update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181875/synchronous-redraw-in-webkit-wait-for-dom-update)
- [How to force repaint in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953871/how-to-force-repaint-in-js)

However, I don't have control over the code making the synchronous request.

EDIT: another related post:

- [Force UI repaint in Webkit (Safari & Chrome) right before Synchronous "Ajax" request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040279/force-ui-repaint-in-webkit-safari-chrome-right-before-synchronous-ajax-req)

Comment: Just fyi, `oldSend.bind(this)(...args)` could be `oldSend.apply(this, args)`

Comment: Since you can monkey-patch this function, why not alter your dom, then call the original slow synchronous function on a short `setTimeout`?  Looking forward to seeing "right" way of doing this :-).

Comment: No, this is not possible. You can force a reflow, but not a repaint. And btw, cases like this are exactly why SJAX is deprecated.

Comment: @JoshuaR. The library makes many, many of these requests, and they are generally not triggered by something I call. I don't think I have a way to delay the request.

Comment: @JoshuaR. Had the same idea, and it would work for `send` in particular since it returns `undefined` anyway, but then the response would be immediately available to the caller.

Comment: yeah, that's true... with that in mind, there's no solution other than finding a better lib

Comment: Which library is it? You’ll probably just need to fix it.

Comment: @Ryan It's some proprietary software (not ours). I don't have any access to any of the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation of why screen updates are not possible in the middle of executing synchronous code may be found in the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops):

> 8.1.4.1 Definitions
>
> To coordinate events, user interaction, scripts, rendering, networking, and so forth, user agents must use event loops as described in this section.

which implies rendering is a separate call out from the event loop in relation to call outs that execute scripts.

This is further detailed under the processing model:

> 8.1.4.2 Processing model
>
> ....  pick a task and run it [ steps 1-6]
>
> 7. **Update the rendering**: If this event loop is a browsing context event loop (as opposed to a worker event loop), then run the following substeps.
>
> ....

Hence it is not possible to update the screen from within a browsing context in the middle of executing synchronous code in a single call out from the event loop.

Moving synchronous code to a web worker might form the basis of a solution (workers execute in a separate thread) but is outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: I don't think this would prevent an API that allows manually invoking these steps from a script, but yeah it's not designed to need one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is not possible, based on comments on the question, research, and my own experience.

For my use case, I'll make the page "freezing" the loading indicator, by having something on the page that is always animated. Or, more likely, just forgo the loading indicator feature.

Comment: If anyone has concrete evidence that a synchronous repaint is not possible, post that as an answer, and I will accept it.